# iOS Swift: retrieve an entry from the database for the user currently logged in

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

How do I retrieve a value (other than username and user id, which seem easier to get) for the current user from the database.

Ironically, I can set the value as follows and that works just fine:

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
userID = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)! as String
databaseRef.child("users").child(userID!).child("TermCond").setValue("Yes")
```

But for the life of me I cannot work out what to put instead of `setValue` if I simply want to retrieve the current `TermCond` value. I thought just using `value` as for example in

```
let DesiredValue = databaseRef.child("users").child(userID!).child("TermCond").value as? String
```

Would suffice, but nothing works. I am confused why retrieving the value should be more difficult than setting it.

Comment: You'll need to observe a value event as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "read" a value from Firebase, you need to add a reference listener that gets called every time that value changes.

In your case, that could be something like:

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
databaseRef.child("users").child(userID!).child("TermCond").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let desiredValue = snapshot.value as? String
})
```

This block of code will get triggered **every time** your value changes. If you only want to read it once, you can use `observeSingleEvent:of:with` instead of `observe:with`.

This is as described in the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

I recommend you read their entire *[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)* to get an idea of how Firebase works, as it is very different from traditional databases.

I can also recommend the following tutorial if you'd like to learn a bit more about the Firebase Database and how it works: https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2

Comment: Thank you so much, this was extremely helpful and allowed me to solve my problem! Thanks also for the links which I will study, especially since they are Swift 3.

Comment: @AJGronevelt you are very welcome! In general I can recommend the Ray Wenderlich tutorials on a number of subjects as they're always up-to-date on the latest iOS, Swift and Xcode editions, and cover a lot of topics in great detail with excellent readability. They also have a few more Firebase tutorials that would be helpful if you're interested in really learning Firebase, though they're specific to things such as creating a messaging applications etc. Just search for "Firebase" on their website!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this now (based on Aleksander's reply). The way I did it is as follows.

```
databaseRef.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.desiredValue = value?["TermCond"] as? String ?? ""
        self.LabelToShow.text = self.desiredValue!
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

This works absolutely fine and shows the value of TermCond in the LabelToShow on my iOS screen.

Comment: @Aleksander I didn't realise, sorry. Just accepted your answer!